# Why is an optional array not enumerable in Swift?

Tags: swift

Why is an optional array not enumerable in Swift? What's the best way to make it work?

e.g.

```
var objs:String[]?

// Won't work
for obj in objs {

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You first need to "unwrap" the optional, or in other words, validate if it is `nil` or not:

```
if let actualObjs = objs {
    for obj in actualObjs {
    }
}
```

`actualObjs` becomes type: `String[]` and the block is run with it if `objs` is not `nil`. If  `objs` is `nil`, the block will just be skipped. (For more information on this, read [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_432))

If you are positive that `objs` is not `nil`, you can also just use the force unwrap operator (`!`):

```
for obj in objs! {
}
```

If `objs` is `nil` in this case, it will throw a runtime error and the whole program will stop.

**Note**: The practical reason you need to unwrap the optional, is that an `Optional` is its own type in Swift:

```
enum Optional<T>
```

So when you try to interact with the `Optional` directly, you are really interacting with an enum. That enum just happens to store the real value within it. (hence the name "unwrap")

Comment: What's `let actualObjs = objs` doing? Can you explain?

Comment: @manojlds "if let" is a special syntax for unwrapping optionals (and some other things). There isn't much to be said other than it tests if the optional is nil. If it is not nil, it assigns the value to "actualObjs" as a normal (non-optional) value and runs the `if` block

Comment: @drewag - ah, ok thanks. Is there a documentation link explaining this? Wasn't able to find it.

Comment: @manojlds It is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_432)

Answer (score 3):

**=====Swift 2.1=====**

```
objs?.forEach {
    print($0) // $0 is obj
}
```

the same as

```
objs?.forEach { obj in
    // Do something with `obj`
}
```

**=====Swift 1.2=====**

If you want to enumerate `objs` that is still be `[String]?`,

Try it

```
for i in 0 ..< (objs?.count ?? 0) {
    let obj = objs?[i]
}
```